# How to import addon into its dummy app in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember and have started to build an addon. Currently, I want to build the addon and implement it in an application inside its dummy application (path: tests/dummy/app).

My addon has a component which I want available in the dummy project.

How can we include the addon inside the dummy project ?

(I am using ember version: 1.13.0)

Comment: If you have defined your component in the `addon/components` folder and exported it in the `app/components` folder you should be able to use it in the `dummy` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your addon, if you define `addon/components/my-component.js` and you re-export it in `app/components/my-component.js`, then you should be able to use it normally in the dummy app like `{{my-component}}`.

Note that the ember-cli component generator handles the file locations for you. e.g running `$ ember g component my-component` would yield the files I mentioned above.

Also, you addon project should also be generated using ember-cli using `$ ember addon addon-name`.